# PHP get grandfather dir path

Tags: php, path, magic-constants

I know PHP > 5.3 added the Magic constants : `__DIR__` to get the father dir path,

But how can I get the grandfather dir path in a smarter way?

1.`__DIR__.'/../'`

2.`dirname(__DIR__)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the second parameter `levels` for the **[dirname](http://php.net/dirname)** call

```
echo dirname(__DIR__,2); // 1 Level up = Father. 2 Levels up = Grandfather
```

However, it is not any better than what you already have. It's just smarter like you asked for :)

Comment: It seem a good idea. if the level more than 2, that will be terrible with mine code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move up a folder by using `..`.

For example:

```
$path = dirname(__DIR__);
$grandfatherPath = $path.'/../../';
```